# IntelliJ Codename One Plug-in causes error when creating new Form

Tags: codenameone

I get this error when creating a new Form using IntelliJ. Is this my setup problem or a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug where you have two instances of IntelliJ/IDEA working on the GUI builder together. If only one is open this works as expected.

[This is the issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2050) that tracks it in the issue tracker.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll take note of that. Thanks!